# How to apply str.split() on pandas column?

Tags: pandas, numpy, matrix

Using Simple Data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ids': [0,1,2], 'value': ['2 4 10 0 14', '5 91 19 20 0', '1 1 1 2 44']})
```

I need to convert the column to array, so I use:

```
df.iloc[:,-1] = df.iloc[:,-1].apply(lambda x: str(x).split())
X = df.iloc[:, 1:]
X = np.array(X.values)
```

but the problem is the data is being nested and I just need a matrix (3,5). How to make this properly and fast for large data (avoid looping)?

Comment: `df['value'].str.split()` ?

Comment: Try `df['value'].str.split(expand=True)`

Comment: This works I guess but the problem is `df.iloc[1].str.split()` doesn't. I can't use names.

Comment: `df.iloc[:,1].str.split()` should , because `df.iloc[1]` gives you a row and `df.iloc[:,1]` gives you a column

Comment: Something's not right because after `X = df.iloc[:, 1:]
X = np.array(X.values)` I still have nested lists instead of normal 3x5 array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in the comments by @anky, @ScottBoston. You can use string method split along with expand parameter and finally change to NumPy:

```
df.iloc[:, 1].str.split(expand=True).values

array([['2', '4', '10', '0', '14'],
       ['5', '91', '19', '20', '0'],
       ['1', '1', '1', '2', '44']], dtype=object)
```